# Linux Mint Rosa 17.3 does not boot after install from USB

Tags: linux-mint

[image][image]I have installed Linux Mint 17.3 Xfce via USB and then restarted w/out USB only to see BIOS. I changed the boot priority, changed BIOS to default, and nearly every other forum suggestion on here and Linux-Mint forum and still can't figure out what is wrong. I had Windows 7 but reformatted the disk and no longer have it. When I re-insert my Linux Mint installation USB and go through the Install Linux process from the Desktop, it does show that another OS exists (Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa).  From what I've read, it appears that my BIOS HDD is not finding a boot file???

Comment: What partition or disk did you install to during the installation? What did you set the boot priority to? Do you have a UEFI BIOS? Did you install Mint in UEFI or legacy mode? What happens on boot? We need more information.

Comment: I edited my original post to include a photo of my partitions. I'm relatively new to Linux. I pretty much followed the installation prompts from the USB Linux Mint installation icon. My laptop is a 2011 Lenovo B575 that used to have Windows 7 (deleted after installing Linux) with 4mb RAM and 64-bit. My HDD is 320GB SATA. If I try to reinstall from the USB the prompt recognizes that a version of Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa already exists. I'm starting to thing there's an issue with only being able to restart computer and immediately it goes to BIOS. There is no secure boot option modify.

Comment: During the installation, does it ask about installing the GRUB bootloader? If so, what option did you specify?

Comment: Is it possible my HDD doesn't support UEFI? I do not have any Windows installed. All online suggestions direct me to doing stuff within Windows to convert from MBR to GPT. There isn't a Legacy Mode in my BIOS.

Comment: If your bios isn't UEFI, then don't worry about it. What concerns me most is that on the partition you have flagged as boot, only 4MB is in use. This is why I'm wondering on which partition did you install the GRUB bootloader.

Comment: Could that be the USB that's still connected? If not, can I manually change the size in disk manager within Mint before I restart the computer (after installation)?

Comment: No, in the image you are looking only at /dev/sda which is the 298 GB disk. It's not an issue of partition size, but whether you installed a bootloader. Can you confirm how/where GRUB was installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70775/discussion-between-multithr3at3d-and-chris).

Comment: I finally got LinuxMint 17.3 to boot. I downloaded unetbootin onto another Windows 8 laptop. Then used it to burn boot-repair-disk to a USB. I then inserted USB into problematic computer, clicked through some advanced options, then followed the prompts and ran the copy+paste codes it told me to in a terminal. I can now boot into LinuxMint. I will consider this as solved and now need to figure why I can't use any internet or USB drives to transfer files, etc. I think drivers are missing.